# Communication Problem on Routers with Access Lists

Tags: routes, router, cisco

I tried to use access lists on router. They can contact each other but when i use access lists on Router1. I created an named and extend access list which name was list1. It prevents FTP from 192.168.5.0 to 192.168.1.200.
When i use that access list on Router1 i cannot ping computers.

[image]
Access List

```
Router#conf ter
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
Router(config)#ip ac
Router(config)#ip access-list ex
Router(config)#ip access-list extended list1
Router(config-ext-nacl)#deny tcp 192.168.5.0 255.255.255.0 host 192.168.1.200 eq 80
Router(config-ext-nacl)#exit
Router(config)#serial 
Router(config)#inter
Router(config)#interface seri
Router(config)#interface serial 0/0/0
Router(config-if)#ip a
Router(config-if)#ip acc
Router(config-if)#ip access-group list1 in
Router(config-if)#end
Router#
```

Answer (score 0):

at the end of an access-list, theres a implicit deny any any. in your config you deny port80 between these 2 ips, but you also deny anything else. put a permit any any under your deny statement, then traffic will pass trough interface

but i think you should not post infrastructure related question with no relation to sw-dev here :-)... all the best to you